# Maven not updating dependency

Tags: maven

I'm working with a project that imports an internal SNAPSHOT dependency that has been updated, but the version is still the same.  I cannot get my Maven to get this latest update.

We have an internal Nexus repository.  One of modules contains much of our data model so that it can be leveraged across multiple applications.  This module is at version 1.5.0-SNAPSHOT.  Recently it was updated, however the version was not incremented.  One of the updates was a method was moved from one class to another.  My project calls that method and therefore, this update should break the project's build.

I know for a fact that the module has been updated in Nexus, because when I build this project through Jenkins, it fails because that method was moved.  I also pulled the source code from our VCS to verify directly from the source code.

I have searched SO and here is what I've tried from many of the solutions provided to similar questions.

- `mvn -U clean install`.
- Removed the local repository entry from my .m2/repository folder.
- `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository`
- Using a new local repository with `-Dmaven.repo.local=localrepo`

In pretty much all of these, I can see the dependency getting downloaded from our Nexus server and yet my project still builds successfully.  I have the feeling there's a setting in my Maven environment that needs changed or something.

Comment: I suppose that the build in jenkins is using the default configuration for SNAPSHOT's and does not use `-U` furthermore have you checked the metadata in Nexus if they are correct? If not you need to regenerate the metadata in Nexus..

Comment: Yes, the Jenkins build does not have the -U switch.  I will check about the metadata in Nexus.  Thanks

Comment: So if Jenkins does not has the `-U` option it will likely use the old version and that will explain the first part that it will work on your CI Server ...furthermore I would check the metadata...

Comment: there is also a setting for the updatePolicy in settings.xml: https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.0/maven-settings/settings.html - this is a per repository setting. the default for snapshots is daily. in your case i would check the mvn help:effective-settings and mvn help:effective-pom so you are sure you work with the local repo you think you are (check both command line and IDE).